# List of Cisco ASA pre-defined services

Tags: firewall, cisco, service, cisco-asa

Where/How can I get a list of all the services that are pre-defined on a Cisco ASA device?

For example, I can do the following in a config:

```
object-group service ALLOWTOSERVER
 service-object tcp www
 service-object tcp https
```

And the ASA will know to allow port 80 and 443 though, but I can't find a list anywhere that describes all the services an ASA knows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if there is one on the web, but you can do `service-object tcp ?` or `service-object udp ?` and it will list out every service that it knows about. If you want it for future reference just copy and paste it out of your terminal and save it to a text file.

Answer (score 6):

Using Zypher's suggestion, and to save other people time in the future, here is the list from an ASA5505 using version 8.0.4:

```
: TCP
aol
bgp
chargen
cifs
citrix-ica
cmd
ctiqbe
daytime
discard
domain
echo
exec
finger
ftp
ftp-data
gopher
h323
hostname
http
https
ident
imap4
irc
kerberos
klogin
kshell
ldap
ldaps
login
lotusnotes
lpd
netbios-ssn
nfs
nntp
pcanywhere-data
pim-auto-rp
pop2
pop3
pptp
rsh
rtsp
sip
smtp
sqlnet
ssh
sunrpc
tacacs
talk
telnet
uucp
whois
www

: UDP
biff
bootpc
bootps
cifs
discard
dnsix
domain
echo
http
isakmp
kerberos
mobile-ip
nameserver
netbios-dgm
netbios-ns
nfs
ntp
pcanywhere-status
pim-auto-rp
radius
radius-acct
rip
secureid-udp
sip
snmp
snmptrap
sunrpc
syslog
tacacs
talk
tftp
time
who
www
xdmcp
```

Comment: +1 for the complete list

Answer (score 1):

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa98/configuration/general/asa-98-general-config/ref-ports.html

Cisco has the list as in link above.